# Installation question: initdb is missing after install of postgis2 via RPMS on RHEL 6.4

Tags: postgis, installation, linux

I'm attempting to install postgis2 on RHEL 6.4 by using the instructions postgis.net/install, but after the postgis2 install, neither initdb nor /etc/init.d/postgreql92 is present.  The same thing happens with the
9.3 beta.  Is a source installation my best option?

**DETAILS**

```
[root@pgsrv ~]# cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

[root@pgsrv ~]# rpm -qa | grep post
postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64

[root@pgsrv ~]# rpm -qa | grep pgdg

[root@pgsrv ~]# rpm -ihv pgdg-redhat92-9.2-7.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:pgdg-redhat92          ########################################### [100%]

[root@pgsrv ~]# cd /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/
[root@pgsrv pluginconf.d]# ls
changelog.conf               product-id.conf          security.conf              versionlock.conf
downloadonly.conf            rhnplugin.conf           subscription-manager.conf  versionlock.list
epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm  rhnplugin.conf-original  verify.conf
[root@pgsrv pluginconf.d]# cat rhnplugin.conf
[main]
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1

# Added "exclude=postgresql*" for PostGIS 
exclude=postgresql*

# You can specify options per channel, e.g.:
#
#[rhel-i386-server-5]
#enabled = 1
#
#[some-unsigned-custom-channel]
#gpgcheck = 0


[root@pgsrv pluginconf.d]# yum install postgis2*
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, product-id, rhnplugin, security, verify, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgis2_92.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql92 for package: postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdal.so.1()(64bit) for package: postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
---> Package postgis2_92-debuginfo.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6 will be installed
---> Package postgis2_92-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6 will be installed
---> Package postgis2_92-docs.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6 will be installed
---> Package postgis2_92-utils.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-Pg for package: postgis2_92-utils-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdal.x86_64 0:1.7.3-15.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-Pg.x86_64 0:2.15.1-4.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package postgresql92.x86_64 0:9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6 will be installed
---> Package postgresql92-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch              Version                       Repository                       Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 postgis2_92                      x86_64            2.0.3-2.rhel6                 pgdg92                          2.5 M
 postgis2_92-debuginfo            x86_64            2.0.3-2.rhel6                 pgdg92                          1.5 M
 postgis2_92-devel                x86_64            2.0.3-2.rhel6                 pgdg92                          172 k
 postgis2_92-docs                 x86_64            2.0.3-2.rhel6                 pgdg92                          3.7 M
 postgis2_92-utils                x86_64            2.0.3-2.rhel6                 pgdg92                           31 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gdal                             x86_64            1.7.3-15.el6                  epel                            3.0 M
 perl-DBD-Pg                      x86_64            2.15.1-4.el6_3                rhel-x86_64-server-6            196 k
 postgresql92                     x86_64            9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6             pgdg92                          970 k
 postgresql92-libs                x86_64            9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6             pgdg92                          185 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install       9 Package(s)

Total download size: 12 M
Installed size: 53 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/9): gdal-1.7.3-15.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                              | 3.0 MB     00:00     
(2/9): perl-DBD-Pg-2.15.1-4.el6_3.x86_64.rpm                                                     | 196 kB     00:00     
(3/9): postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                                      | 2.5 MB     00:00     
(4/9): postgis2_92-debuginfo-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                            | 1.5 MB     00:00     
(5/9): postgis2_92-devel-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                                | 172 kB     00:00     
(6/9): postgis2_92-docs-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                                 | 3.7 MB     00:00     
(7/9): postgis2_92-utils-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                                |  31 kB     00:00     
(8/9): postgresql92-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                                 | 970 kB     00:00     
(9/9): postgresql92-libs-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm                                            | 185 kB     00:00     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                   9.2 MB/s |  12 MB     00:01     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : postgresql92-libs-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                           1/9 
  Installing : postgresql92-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                                2/9 
  Installing : gdal-1.7.3-15.el6.x86_64                                                                             3/9 
  Installing : postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                                     4/9 
  Installing : perl-DBD-Pg-2.15.1-4.el6_3.x86_64                                                                    5/9 
  Installing : postgis2_92-utils-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                               6/9 
  Installing : postgis2_92-devel-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                               7/9 
  Installing : postgis2_92-docs-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                                8/9 
  Installing : postgis2_92-debuginfo-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                           9/9 
  Verifying  : postgis2_92-debuginfo-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                           1/9 
  Verifying  : postgis2_92-docs-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                                2/9 
  Verifying  : postgis2_92-devel-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                               3/9 
  Verifying  : postgresql92-libs-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                           4/9 
  Verifying  : postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                                     5/9 
  Verifying  : postgresql92-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64                                                                6/9 
  Verifying  : postgis2_92-utils-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64                                                               7/9 
  Verifying  : gdal-1.7.3-15.el6.x86_64                                                                             8/9 
  Verifying  : perl-DBD-Pg-2.15.1-4.el6_3.x86_64                                                                    9/9 

Installed:
  postgis2_92.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6                       postgis2_92-debuginfo.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6                
  postgis2_92-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6                 postgis2_92-docs.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6                     
  postgis2_92-utils.x86_64 0:2.0.3-2.rhel6                

Dependency Installed:
  gdal.x86_64 0:1.7.3-15.el6                               perl-DBD-Pg.x86_64 0:2.15.1-4.el6_3                          
  postgresql92.x86_64 0:9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6                  postgresql92-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6                 

Complete!

[root@pgsrv pluginconf.d]# cd /usr/
[root@pgsrv usr]# cd pgsql-9.2
[root@pgsrv pgsql-9.2]# cd bin
[root@pgsrv bin]# ls
clusterdb   createuser  dropuser       pg_dump         pg_restore     psql          shp2pgsql
createdb    dropdb      pg_basebackup  pg_dumpall      pgsql2shp      raster2pgsql  vacuumdb
createlang  droplang    pg_config      pg_receivexlog  pg_test_fsync  reindexdb

[root@pgsrv bin]# cd /etc/init.d
[root@pgsrv init.d]# ls
abrt-ccpp         cgconfig   iptables      network                 postgresql-9.3.rpmsave  rpcsvcgssd      trace-cmd
abrtd             cgred      irqbalance    nfs                     psacct                  rsyslog         tuned
abrt-oops         crond      kdump         nfslock                 qpidd                   sandbox         udev-post
acpid             cups       killall       nscd                    quota_nld               saslauthd       wdaemon
arptables_jf      dbora      ktune         nslcd                   rdisc                   single          winbind
arpwatch          dovecot    lvm2-lvmetad  ntpd                    restorecond             spamassassin    xinetd
atd               firstboot  lvm2-monitor  ntpdate                 rhnsd                   spice-vdagentd
auditd            functions  mcelogd       oddjobd                 rhsmcertd               sshd
autofs            haldaemon  mdmonitor     portreserve             rngd                    svnserve
avahi-daemon      halt       messagebus    postfix                 rpcbind                 sysstat
blk-availability  ip6tables  netconsole    postgresql-9.3-data-pg  rpcgssd                 systemtap
certmonger        ipsec      netfs         postgresql-9.3-orig     rpcidmapd               tcsd

[root@pgsrv init.d]# yum provides */initdb
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, product-id, rhnplugin, security, verify, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
elrepo-s6-x86_64/filelists                                                                       | 132 kB     00:00     
epel/filelists_db                                                                                | 7.6 MB     00:07     
pgdg92/filelists_db                                                                              | 157 kB     00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-6/filelists                                                                   |  25 MB     00:03     
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6/filelists                                                          | 9.3 MB     00:01     
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-6/filelists                                                     | 1.4 MB     00:00     
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-6/filelists                                                         |  57 kB     00:00     
postgresql92-server-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 : The programs needed to create and run a PostgreSQL server
Repo        : pgdg92
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/initdb

postgresql92-debuginfo-9.2.3-2PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 : Debug information for package postgresql92
Repo        : pgdg92
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/src/debug/postgresql-9.2.3/src/bin/initdb

postgresql92-server-9.2.3-2PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 : The programs needed to create and run a PostgreSQL server
Repo        : pgdg92
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/initdb

postgresql92-debuginfo-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64 : Debug information for package postgresql92
Repo        : pgdg92
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/src/debug/postgresql-9.2.4/src/bin/initdb

[root@pgsrv init.d]# rpm -qa | grep post
postgis2_92-docs-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql92-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgis2_92-utils-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
postgis2_92-devel-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
postgis2_92-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql92-libs-9.2.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgis2_92-debuginfo-2.0.3-2.rhel6.x86_64

[root@pgsrv init.d]# rpm -ql postgis2_92| grep initdb
[root@pgsrv init.d]# rpm -ql postgis2_92 | wc
    239     239   14920
[root@pgsrv init.d]# 
[root@pgsrv init.d]# rpm -ql postgresql92 | wc
    327     327   15799
[root@pgsrv init.d]# rpm -ql postgresql92 | grep initdb
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/initdb-9.2.mo
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the actual postgresql server installation. The package is called "postgresql92-server". The instructions indeed are missing this information.